# How to indicate the currently clocked-in task?

Tags: org-mode, highlighting, org-clock, fringe

I'm using org-mode's clocking functions to track the hours I spend on projects. Since my main org file is rather large and I scroll through it a lot, it would be great to have a visual cue of the task that's currently clocked in.

Ideally some marker (e.g. a red arrow) in the fringe would be nice, especially if it 'moves' to the parent header if the subheaders are collapsed. Alternatively a highlighted line would be an options (somewhat similar to `hl-line-mode`, but fixed to the current task (or its parent)). Unfortunately my (e)lisp skills are almost non existent, so I don't have much of a clue where to start. Going through the Emacs manual it looks like [`overlay-arrow-string` and `overlay-arrow-position`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlay-Arrow.html#Overlay-Arrow) are the variables I could use, and `org-clock-in-hook` and `org-clock-out-hook` from `org-clock.el` look like places where I could (un)set these variables.

I know you can easily jump to the current task with `C-c C-x C-j`, but a visual cue would be much appreciated.

Comment: It should appear in modeline.